# Using BIOS interrupts in x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to implement string operations on QEmu in real-mode. Here is the read and print function that I made:

```
int readString(char* line)
{
 int i = 0;
 char in = 0x0;
 while (in != 0xd)
   {
    in = interrupt(0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
    *(line + i) = in;
    interrupt(0x10,0xe*0x100+in,0x0,0x0,0x0);
    i++;
   }
 *(line + i) = 0x0;
 return i;
}

int printString(char* string)
{
 int i = 0;
 while (*(string + i) != '\0')
   {
    char al = *(string + i);
    char ah = 0xe;
    int ax = ah * 256 + al;
    interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);
    i++;
   }
 return i;
}
```

These functions are called in the following main program:

```
void main()
{
 char* line;
 printString("Reading from input:\n\r");
 readString(line);
 printString("Line read is:\n\r");
 printString(line);
}
```

The readString function takes the input from the keyboard, prints it to the screen (on QEmu) as we type the input string and stores the result in the argument passed (which is pointer to char). 
But the cursor doesn't seem to move after the readString function. And the call to printString function afterwards (in the main function) causes the string to be overwritten. For example, if I write "Hello ", then I expect output to be:

```
Reading from input:
Hello Line read is:
Hello _
```

Here "_" is the cursor.
But instead the actual output coming is:

```
Reading from input:
Line read is:
Hello
```

The cursor is under the "H" of the Hello above (in actual output) and the initial "Hello" in the second line of the expected output is overwritten. Why is the cursor not moving as I print the string?

Comment: My guess is because it is not actually being typed, it is just putting it to the viewing screen.

Comment: But I am using the bios interrupt 0x10 to type the input read from keyboard so it should be actually typed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user presses enter, you will get the `CR` character (code 13, `\r`). However the bios output function interprets this as strictly a carriage return, that is it moves the cursor back to the start of the line. You need to add the `LF` (code 10, `\n`) yourself. For example:

```
int readString(char* line)
{
 int i = 0;
 char in = 0x0;
 while (in != 0xd)
   {
    in = interrupt(0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);
    *(line + i) = in;
    interrupt(0x10,0xe*0x100+in,0x0,0x0,0x0);
    /* add LF to CR */
    if (in == 13) interrupt(0x10,0xe*0x100+10,0x0,0x0,0x0);
    i++;
   }
 *(line + i) = 0x0;
 return i;
}

int printString(char* string)
{
 int i = 0;
 while (*(string + i) != '\0')
   {
    char al = *(string + i);
    char ah = 0xe;
    int ax = ah * 256 + al;
    interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);
    /* add LF to CR */
    if (al == 13) interrupt(0x10,0xe*0x100+10,0x0,0x0,0x0);
    i++;
   }
 return i;
}
```

[image: qemu screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Jester....one more problem with above code is that it is not working for large input strings. Could you please also help me with this

Comment: by large string I mean string that is 30 or more characters.  And not working is that  the line "Line read is:"  doesn't get printed and for 43 characters or so nothing happens after pressing enter

Comment: Well, on closer look we can see you are not allocating any space so it's sheer luck that your program even works at all... `line` in `main()` is totally uninitialized. Maybe try something like `char line[80];` or similar? PS: Do you know C?

Comment: But I am using pointer do I really need to allocate space? Can I not form array of any length using pointer indexing

Comment: Yes you need to allocate space, otherwise you will just write into memory randomly.